# How to make pizza without pizza sauce?

Tags: sauce, pizza

Does anyone know how to make pizza without pizza sauce? Maybe some kind of replacement?

Comment: You mean tomato sauce? Then just cheese, maybe several kinds as long as they melt nicely. Depending g on your oven you may want to bake your base alone first, in this case I brush some olive oil. Or just olive oil and salt flakes and call it focaccia. Or Pizza bianca if you want to call it pizza;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Focaccia dough stretched and rolled thin, painted with olive oil, sprinkled with fresh herbs and coarse salt then lanced about with a fork is a wonderful pizza with no need for any sauce or other toppings as a snack of side dish.  From there as a starting point you can start adding toppings, cheeses, even sauces to ones hearts content.  Herbs could be dried rather than fresh, but fresh basil or oregano are a good starting point.  I love a good sauce, but in no way is any sauce needed for a pizza.  If you want a sauce however, most anything that pairs with your toppings will work and there is no reason to skimp on creativity.  BBQ with chicken or shredded pork.  An Alfredo with shrimp or chicken.  A yogurt with fresh fruits for dessert.  There really are no rules.  Pizza is in my opinion defined by location and taste, not by some specific definition and is fully open to interpretation.  With a good base if needs no sauce.  With a lesser base, yes I want a sauce, but not to be limited to what some shop defined as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Pizza can be made with all kinds of sauces, that’s the best part about pizza, it’s so flexible. My best friend is allergic to tomatoes, so I either use an Alfredo sauce as a base for her pizza or pesto. You could also make a buffalo or type of hot sauce, or a barbecue sauce and vary the toppings along with those sauces. You could also put like a tikka masala simmer sauce on a pizza and make it Indian style with chicken!

Answer (score 0):

If you still want a red sauce you can make your own.  Store-bought spaghetti sauce is usually too thin and sweet, something like ketchup is also too sweet and has an odd flavor on pizza (though I've had pizza in Hungary that had ketchup on it).  You can mix these with tomato sauce or fresh tomatoes to get a good tomato sauce.

But you can put anything on a pizza, my favorite non-tomato sauce is caramelized onions.  There is a traditional French pizza called "Pissaladiere" which has caramelized onions, olives, and usually capers and anchovies.  The onions also go great with bacon.